# Would a question asking for examples of unobservable posits in physical theories be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

The title really says it all: would a question asking for examples of unobservable [posits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posit) in physical theories be appropriate for this SE?

I know that requests for lists are generally frowned upon. Is this question fine as is? If not, is there some way to reformulate it into an acceptable one?

Comment: Well, I do not speak for everyone or for our policy on lists, so kindly ignore my diamond for the purposes of this comment. That said: *git the torches and pitchforks, boys!*

Comment: @dmckee Haha, can I take that to mean that (at least you) do not approve of this sort of question?

Comment: Dennis, yeah. I'm pretty down on anything that resembles a list questions. But my position is more extreme than the general consensus.

Answer (score 2):

As DavidZ pointed out to me on another answer of mine, we can't say whether something is on or off topic until we see the question's wording. So if you don't get what you need in chat, edit your question here with the wording of what you intend to ask and we can help shape it if it can be shaped or tell you to bugger off :)

And, even if I post something that says "Yeah, looks great!" that really can only say it ***might*** be on-topic, it's up to the community to really decide.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it would not be appropriate. You could bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), though.

Comment: Ah! Good suggestion, I always forget that chat can be used for productive things too....